# Pluck stops working when dropping first and last record in a variable with Active Record Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the model I have the following scope:

```
scope :rent_conditions, ->(all_rent_conditions, arguments) { where(all_rent_conditions, arguments) }
```

I call the scope:

```
Rent.rent_conditions(all_rent_conditions, arguments).order(fermetraverd: :asc)
```

In the controller variable:

```
@rent_filter_results
```

Receives 10 Active Record Relations from the search on Rent.

Now I want to drop the first and last record from the search so I:

```
Rent.rent_conditions(all_rent_conditions, arguments).order(fermetraverd: :asc).values_at(1..8)
```

Records 2 - 9 are correctly returned to the controller.

But pluck throws an error on the following statement that was working before I dropped first and last record:

```
size = @rent_filter_results.pluck(:flatarmal)
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x007faa293e3ac0>
```

It seems that pluck is trying to access the first record that I was trying to drop. Or maybe I don't fully understand what is going on. Can someone explain and suggest how I can drop the first and last Active Record Relation and have Pluck still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `values_at` converts your object from `ActiveRelation` to an `Array`. You may try the following code.

```
Rent.rent_conditions(all_rent_conditions, arguments).order(fermetraverd: :asc).offset(1).limit(8)
```

And then `pluck` can be called on the result. i.e:

```
size = @rent_filter_results.pluck(:flatarmal)
```